# Terminating a process specially in QEMU

Tags: intel, qemu

**Example code:**

```
  int main () {

      printf("Hello world begin\n");

      // New instruction
      __asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x0f\n\t"
                            ".byte 0xd0\n\t"
                            :);

      printf("Hello world end\n");

      return 0;
  }
```

**My problem [TLDR]** :

Make QEMU treat my new instruction similar to return 0; [sys_exit]

**My purpose**:

I am trying to customize the QEMU emulation of x86 ISA to log some data (like number of ring transitions etc) during CPU emulation between two points. Assume for simplicity, the start will be after the first printf (or some syscall) and end will be marked by a new instruction that I have written (say opcode '0f d0' which is unused in Intel ISA) whose purpose is to simply print those log information and terminate the process there (in line 2) and without executing the rest of the lines. In other words, the behavior should be identical to a scenario where *'return 0;'* was placed right after my new instruction.

In my QEMU helper logic, I tried to add *cpu_loop_exit()* and all other combinations, they seem to loop infinitely. Can anyone point me how to achieve the behavior I want (with only modifying QEMU and not my example code) ?